# How to solve the gnu grub version 2.04 error?

Tags: grub2

When I entered ubuntu which I recently installed it sort of glitched and refreshed it's page 3 or 4 times and now it's starting to show gnu grub version 2.04 error whenever I try to boot ubuntu.

In gnu grub version 2.04 After reaching here:

`ls (hd0,gpt1)/efi/ubuntu/`

It shows these options:

`grubx64.efi shimx64.efi mmx64.efi bootx64.efi grub.cfg`

I have no idea what to do after this. Please help as soon as possible

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Are you booting in UEFI boot mode? Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: any solution on this? I installed Ubuntu 18.04 and reinstalled Ubuntu 20.04 (remove the 18.04 one). Is it possible that this cause this problem?